# angular js binding and Controlle example error

Tags: angularjs

Exercise.js :

```
var myAppModule = angular.module("myFirstModule", []);

var MyAppController = function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Welcome to Angular Tutorial";
};

myAppModule.controller = ("MyAppController", MyAppController);
```

Html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head ng-app="myFirstModule">
    <script src="Scripts/Excercise.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MyAppController">
        1+5 =  {{ 1 + 5 }}
        <br />
        {{['nikhil','om','sai'] [2]}}
        <br />
        {{ {name:'nikhil',details:'om sai ' }.name }}
        <br />
        {{ message }}

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When i am trying to solve this i am getting error. I Know its a small error but i am not able to figure this out.

Comment: This is the output i am getting 1+5 = {{ 1 + 5 }} 
{{['nikhil','om','sai'] [2]}} 
{{ {name:'nikhil',details:'om sai ' }.name }} 
{{ message }}

Comment: Change `myAppModule.controller = ("MyAppController", MyAppController);` to `myAppModule.controller("MyAppController", MyAppController);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @Sajeetharan's answer above, there is also one minor issue that your Exercises.js script may not be getting loaded:

```
<script src="Scripts/Excercise.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
```

The `~` is missing, so the code is dependent on where the HTML file is located(it'll look in the current directory). The `angular.js` script tag is not dependent.

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues

(i) Change your controller as,

```
 myAppModule.controller('MyAppController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Welcome to Angular Tutorial";
    });
```

(ii) Load **`angular.js`** script before loading your **`script.js`**

(iii) Place **`ng-app`** ahead of body

**DEMO**

```js
var myAppModule = angular.module("myFirstModule", []);

myAppModule.controller('MyAppController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Welcome to Angular Tutorial";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head >
</head>
<body ng-app="myFirstModule">
    <div ng-controller="MyAppController">
        1+5 =  {{ 1 + 5 }}
        <br />
        {{['nikhil','om','sai'] [2]}}
        <br />
        {{ {name:'nikhil',details:'om sai ' }.name }}
        <br />
        {{ message }}

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your controller to

```
myAppModule.controller('MyAppController', function ($scope) {
        // your code goes here
    });
```

### **or**

```
 var MyAppController = function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Welcome to Angular Tutorial";
};
myAppModule.controller("MyAppController", MyAppController);
```